# How to handle this routing situation is Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i prefer writing the routes of my Rails applications by hand and i now have a situation where i am not sure what is the best way to do things. I want to have a building controller that shows a different page for every building like :

```
building/town_center
building/sawmill
..
```

Each of the above should have its own action and view page. I would normally create a route like:

```
  scope :path => '/building', :controller => :building do
    get '/view/:slug' => :view, :as => 'view_building'
  end
```

But this only specifies a single action that would then need to call another internal controller method to redirect to the needed template to show. So, i would like your opinion, would you just specify a different route for every building(and action) explicitly ? Or just redirect in the view_building action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after something like this:

```
  match "/building/:name", :to => "buildings#show", :as => :building
```

Then in your controller action 'show' just render template for the building name:

```
  render :template => 'buildings/#{params[:name]}'
```

Comment: I see, so you are thinking of a single route, i would also think this is probably the best way to go, thanx.

Comment: the only problem i am having with that is how to handle possible different data in a single action though. A town center might have a variable named info, while a sawmill might have one named report. This is why i was thinking about using more actions :/ I'm a little uncertain about that.

Comment: If you are doing logic in your controller with variables,  I would recommend moving them into your model.  Following fat model skinny controller principles

Comment: it's not logic really, it's just setting instance variables, which belongs to a controller. The problem is that if a have a single action that redirects to each view template, i would probably have to have many ifs to set different instance variables.

Comment: Ah I see. Yea well it's prob a choice of if you want multiple actions or a switch statement. Prob best practice to stay with the single action and use switch or similar